# RxJS - Epic Reads Only 1 Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, epic

I have an Epic. I want to pass 2 HTTP Get Requests. They are both Promised based. But it only bring data for the first processed one. THE Epic:

```
const processorsListEpic = (action$, store, deps) =>
  action$.ofType(Type.LIST_ATTEMPT).pipe(
    switchMap(() =>
      observableFromHttpPromise(
        deps.getList(store), // This bring data
        deps.getTargets(store) // This doesn't
      ).pipe(
        mergeMap((listResult, targetResult) => {
          console.log('Target:', targetResult.data);
          console.log('List', listResult.data);
          return of(
            R.mergeAll(
              Actions.ListSuccess(listResult && listResult.data),
              Actions.TargetsSuccess(targetResult && targetResult.data)
            )
          );
        }),
        catchError(error => of(Actions.ListFailure(error)))
      )
    )
  );
```

The function `observableFromHttpPromise` is the following:

```
// From is from rxjs
export const observableFromHttpPromise = promise => from(promise);
```

Any Ideas? If I change the order of the requests, the other data are there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
observableFromHttpPromise(Promise.all(
        deps.getList(store),
        deps.getTargets(store),
      ))
```

Comment: Actually, I came up with a similar approach. I used `Promise.All`, and removed the `observableFromHttpPromise` in favour of `from` from RxJS. Thank you!!